# How do I globally handle all type of Exception in NESTJS

Tags: nestjs

error: Error: Duplicate entry 'Story of Lawyer' for key 'book.book-title-unique'
at Packet.asError (E:\Work\nest_best_practice\node_modules\mysql2\lib\packets\packet.js:728:17)
at Query.execute (E:\Work\nest_best_practice\node_modules\mysql2\lib\commands\command.js:29:26)
at PoolConnection.handlePacket (E:\Work\nest_best_practice\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:456:32)
at PacketParser.onPacket (E:\Work\nest_best_practice\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:85:12)
at PacketParser.executeStart (E:\Work\nest_best_practice\node_modules\mysql2\lib\packet_parser.js:75:16)
at Socket. (E:\Work\nest_best_practice\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:92:25)
at Socket.emit (node:events:527:28)
at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:315:12)
at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:289:9)
at Socket.Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:228:10) {
code: 'ER_DUP_ENTRY',
errno: 1062,
sqlState: '23000',
sqlMessage: "Duplicate entry 'Story of Lawyer' for key 'book.book-title-unique'",
sql: "INSERT INTO `book`(`id`, `title`, `desc`, `createdAt`, `updatedAt`, `image`, `pdf`) VALUES (DEFAULT, 'Story of Lawyer', 'No Description', DEFAULT, DEFAULT, 'software-developer-copy-6d00.jpg', 'NEST CLI-3339.pdf')"
}

Comment: This errors shouldn't display in console  and the message that I want to send to client as per my requirement

Comment: Event I use Try catch the error still be displayed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using an exception filter

https://docs.nestjs.com/exception-filters

Comment: I want to Handle the Error that is throw by TypeORM or MySql This Filters are handling only NEST Concern

Comment: You can wrap the call to mysql in a try - catch block and then throw a custom exception i.e HttpException